# Swift - self.navigationController is nil

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I have a strange issue with navigation stack.

***Overview***: I have three view controllers (e.g `AViewController`, `BViewController`, `CViewController`) with two navigation possibilities:

1. `AViewController` to `CViewController`.
2. `AViewController` to `BViewController` to `CViewController`, **or**

And `AViewController` is embedded in a `UINavigationController`. I am using segues for transitions, all defined in storyboard. And all segues are of `Show (e.g. Push)` type. And all the transitions are performed using `performSegueWithIdentifier(String, AnyObject?)` method.

***Problem***: With the first transition, everything works fine. *Everything* means `self.navigationController.popViewController(animated)` in CViewController works fine, to go back to `AViewController`. But with second transition, `self.navigationController` is `nil` in `CViewController`, although it is not `nil` in `BViewController`.

So where am I getting wrong ?

Comment: please show your code and possinly a screenshot of your storyboard

Comment: Oh I will, whenever I'll get the time.

Comment: I was having the same issue, when I used slide view controllers in my app, sharing the sample will help me to understand the exact issue, and could help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how I had created the `Segue`, but I recreated `Segue` from `BViewController` to `CViewController` and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboard,you may want use navigationcontroller instead of custom segues. Therefore you will not need to set the navigations programatically. UINavigationControler set the navigations automatically to back or forward.